# Allow update on specific collection property

Tags: meteor

I am trying to add a "ratings" property to a collection and want to enable ANY user (not just the owner) to be able to add a rating to the ratings set within a collection.  My problem is that I have allow/deny rules set up so that only the owner can perform updates to collections that they own.  Is there a way to allow any user to update a collection only if they are updating a specific property (the "ratings" set), and deny them update access if they are trying to update any other property.

My allow/deny rules on the server are as follows...

```
Playlists.allow({
  insert: function(userId, doc) {
    return (userId && doc.owner === userId);
  },
  update: function (userId, docs, fields, modifier) {
    return _.all(docs, function(doc) {
      return doc.owner === userId;
    });
  },
  remove: function (userId, docs) {
    return _.all(docs, function(doc) {
      return doc.owner === userId;
    });
  }
});

Playlists.deny({
  update: function (userId, docs, fields, modifier) {
    return _.contains(fields, 'owner');
  },
  remove: function (userId, docs) {
    return _.any(docs, function (doc) {
      return doc.locked;
    });
  },
  fetch: ['locked']
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In `Playlists.deny.update`, you can change the logic so that it first checks whether anyone is trying to modify the ratings property (eg. with `$addToSet`) and `return false` if so. So you'd end up with code like this:

```
 Playlists.deny({
    update: function(userId, docs, fields, modifier) {
      if (fields.ratings && modifier["$addToSet"] && modifier["$addToSet"].ratings) {
        return false; // don't deny this
      }
      else {
        return _.contains(fields, 'owner');
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: I tried doing exactly this but it didn't seem to work.  So, I added similar checks in the allow function and it worked.  The only problem was that it caused internal service errors with other types of updates to the Playlists collection.  I'm not sure if this is the correct solution or if the problems I'm facing are just specific to my application.  Thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score -2):

Create a Meteor.methods({updateRatePlaylist:myUpdateRatePlaylistFunction})